# Can a player who is out of bounds help a teammate stay in-bounds?

Tags: rules, american-football

This question came up among my friends while we were watching the Packers triumph over the Giants this evening:

Suppose a receiver is catching a pass along the sideline.  He's got one foot in-bounds, but is falling out-of-bounds.  A teammate also happens to be there; the teammate is out-of-bounds, but pushes the receiver to keep him from falling out-of-bounds, and the receiver gets his second foot down in-bounds.

Could this be considered an in-bounds reception?  Could the receiver then start running?  Is there anything in the rules that prevents an out-of-bounds player from supporting a teammate to stay in-bounds?

Answer (score 7):

Under Rule 12 "Player Conduct" in the 2016 NFL rulebook, Section 1, Article 4 includes the prohibition that

> [n]o offensive player may:
>
> ...
>
> d. push or throw his body against a teammate to aid him in an attempt to obstruct an opponent or to recover a loose ball

Under Rule 3 "Definitions" of the same rulebook, Section 2, Article 4 defines a *loose ball* as

> ... a live ball that is not in player possession, i.e., any ball that has been kicked, passed, or fumbled.

The foul is *illegal use of hands, arms, or body by the offense*, and the penalty is a loss of ten (10) yards.

Part 'a' of the same article in Rule 12  prohibits pulling the runner at all, the foul being *assisting the runner* with identical penalty, and would disallow that act in order to achieve a similar result.